# Buttons "Back, Next and Exit" for Series of Activities

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, onclick

I want to create an app with this series of activities, the layout and animations are different in each activity.

[image]

What is the code for the back, next and exit buttons?
I've been using OnClick Method, it's working fine, but the app SOMETIMES crashes if I click the next button too quick.

```
public void Next(View v){
  Intent next = new Intent(this, NextClass);
  startActivity(next);
  finish();
```

**Is there a better way to do this? Change between activities?**

(I'll appreciate if your answer could be "for dummies", I'm new to Android)

Comment: 1) how about adding logs of that crashes? 2) why finishing all the applications? 3) why adding a back button? every android phone has already a back button. android is not ios!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this? Change between activities?

Yes, there is the better way. Google co. also find out about this restrict when using many Activities.

So they support [Fragment concept](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

You can use

> ActionBarSherlock

combine with :

> ViewPagerIndicator

from GitHub for using Fragment better.

Therefore you can avoid above case :

> I've been using OnClick Method, it's working fine, but the app SOMETIMES crashes if I click the next button too quick.

p/s :

> Fragments decompose application functionality and UI into reusable modules
>
> Add multiple fragments to a screen to avoid switching activities
>
> Fragments have their own lifecycle, state, and back stack
>
> Fragments require API Level 11 or greater